# section id & class definition overwrites container height

Tags: html, css, navbar

Good morning folks, this is only my 2nd question on here, so please bear with me and my minimums:

I just wrote up this lengthy message of how I put the `ID` and `class` commands in a `section` instead of a `container`, and why the section all the sudden overwrote my css height style. I then figured why not replace the # with a . in the CSS file, and voila, it worked again.

However, i know have a new problem. I have a fixed-top bootstrap navigation bar, and when i click on section #2, named Intro, the page scrolls down only a few pixels to display the first line of text. What i had intended was for the site to display the entire intro container. Any suggestions?

I hope this makes sense:

```
<body id="page-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container" id="navigation">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#intro">Intro</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <h1>Welcome to TestZat</h1>

                Lorem....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="login" class="login-section">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <h1>Finde das Login script hier</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="container" id="contact-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1" id="contact">
                Section content TBD
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I answered my own question: I went into the CSS file and added `{padding-top: 50px;}`...For whatever reason, this makes all links jump to the appropriate section and display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Now it will work fine...just remove id from container.

```
    <body id="page-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div  id="navigation">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#intro">Intro</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <h1>Welcome to TestZat</h1>

                Lorem....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="login" class="login-section">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
                <h1>Finde das Login script hier</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="container" id="contact-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1" id="contact">
                Section content TBD
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```